# List in Ionic 3 with Firebase DB

Tags: angular, firebase, ionic-framework, ionic3, angularfire2

I'm using a Firebase DB structured like this:

```
{
"rootList" : {
  "list_1" : {
    "guestsList" : {
      "item_1_1" : {
        "name" : "xxxxx",
        "surname" : "yyyyy"
      }
    },
    "hostName" : "Host_1"
  },
  "list_2" : {
    "guestsList" : {
      "item_2_1" : {
        "name" : "xxxx",
        "surname" : "yyyy"
      },
      "item_2_2" : {
        "name" : "xxx",
        "surname" : "yyy"
      }
    },
    "hostName" : "Host_2"
  },
  "list_3" : {
    "guestsList" : {
      "item_3_1" : {
        "name" : "xxyy",
        "surname" : "yyxx"
      },
      "item_3_2" : {
        "name" : "xyxy",
        "surname" : "yxyx"
      },
      "item_3_3" : {
        "name" : "xyyx",
        "surname" : "yxxy"
      },
      "item_3_4" : {
        "name" : "yxxy",
        "surname" : "xyyx"
      }
    },
    "hostName" : "Host_3"
  }
}
}
```

I retrive the data by `AngularFireDatabase` and `AngularFireList` classes doing this:

```
this.hostsDBList = this.aFDatabase.list('/rootList');
this.hostsList = this.hostsDBList.valueChanges();
```

In my html I've got:

```
<ion-content padding>
  <ion-list *ngFor="let list of hostsList | async">
    <ion-list-header>
      {{ list.hostName }}
    </ion-list-header>

    <ion-item *ngFor="let item of list.guestsList">
      {{ item.name }}
    </ion-item>
  </ion-list>
</ion-content>
```

The headers compare easly, but it gives me an error on the second list of items.
I can't understand if I have to associate an `Observable` for every sub-list too. The error is [image]
I tried to add the `async` Pipe in the `*ngFor` like this:

```
*ngFor="let item of list.guestsList | async"
```

But it gives me another error
[image]

It seems it can't cycle on that type of objects. I can't really understand how to cycle into sub-list from a Firebase list. Some help?

Answer (score 0):

I know it's a bit late, but the error is telling you exactly why it's not working. `guestsList` is not an array, it is an object, therefore you cannot iterate over it.

What you need to do is use a custom pipe to return an array of its property values using [`Object.values()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Object/values) like this

```js
import { PipeTransform, Pipe } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({name: 'values'})
export class ValuesPipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(object, args:string[]) : any {
    return Object.values(object);
  }
}
```

```HTML
<ion-content padding>
  <ion-list *ngFor="let list of hostsList | async">
    <ion-list-header>
      {{ list.hostName }}
    </ion-list-header>

    <ion-item *ngFor="let item of list.guestsList | values">
      {{ item.name }}
    </ion-item>
  </ion-list>
</ion-content>
```

Or you could change `guestsList` into an array, then you won't even need a custom pipe, but you'll lose the `"item_X_X"` keys

```
"guestsList" : [
  {
    "name" : "xxxx",
    "surname" : "yyyy"
  },
  {
    "name" : "xxx",
    "surname" : "yyy"
  }
},
```